# XAMPP MySQL won't start error 1217

Tags: mysql, xampp, runtime-error

I recently got a virus in my computer, and had to reinstall windows. Luckily I have everything on separate HDDs, so I thought it was just to reformat and start XAMPP again. But apparently it wasn't that easy, I keep getting this error message when I try to start MySQL

```
2014-04-18 10:26:35 3200 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-04-18 10:26:35 bb4 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2014-04-18 10:26:35 3200 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-04-18 10:26:35 3200 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-04-18 10:26:35 3200 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-04-18 10:26:35 3200 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-04-18 10:26:35 3200 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2014-04-18 10:26:35 3200 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-04-18 10:26:43 3200 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-04-18 10:26:45 bb4 InnoDB: Operating system error number 1117 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2014-04-18 10:26:45 3200 [ERROR] InnoDB: File D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0: 'Windows aio' returned OS error 1217. Cannot continue operation
```

What can i do to fix it? I don't want to lose the data I have in my MySQL server.

Comment: I gave up and just re installed XAMPP then used getdataback to get back some old backups.

Answer (score 0):

please test this method,copy mysql/data/ibdata1 to another place, if windows couldnt copy that file, this means file crashed with Unwanted windows shutdown.so ibdata1 i/o error Happened. you simlpy must run windows drive error checking on xampp drive. windows automaticaly recover your ibdata1 file.